# Windows phone 8.0 change background several times

Tags: windows-phone-8

I need to change the background color several times during one event , currently I am doing this

```
LayoutRoot.Background = new SolidColorBrush( Colors.Cyan );
```

and its changing the color.
but I want it to be like this

```
    LayoutRoot.Background = new SolidColorBrush( Colors.Cyan );
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    LayoutRoot.Background = new SolidColorBrush( Colors.White );
```

but the problem that the 2nd piece of code changes directly to white , because the change occurs when the execution is done , I want it to be done while the code is executing , any ideas for that ?

Comment: So you want to animate (FADE) from Cyan to White ?

Comment: No , not fading . I just want to change the background in a very quick way . I am doing a torch app that will use front background as light instead of led flash when its not available , so I need it to create S.O.S light

Comment: Oh then want to wrap in a DispatchTimer

Comment: Yes I noticed this , but is there anyway else the timer? Cause for example when I am turning on/off the flash light its being turned on during the code execution

Comment: You can start and stop the DispatchTimer any time you want.

Answer (score 0):

```C#
int state;

// Constructor
public MainPage()
{
    state = 0;

    // create our dispatch timer
    DispatcherTimer timer;
    timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);
    timer.Tick += OnTimerTick;
    timer.Start();
    // timer.Stop();   // call this to stop
}

// if the timer is on, cycle the color
private void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if(state == 0){
           LayoutRoot.Background = new SolidColorBrush( Colors.Cyan );
           state = 1;
        }
        else
        {
           LayoutRoot.Background = new SolidColorBrush( Colors.White );
           state = 0;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string error_message = ex.Message;
    }            
}
```